# identity management in cloud

Tags: claims-based-identity, federated-identity, identity-management

My company is planning to host some applications on public cloud. For identity management in cloud, my understanding is that we have 3 options

1. Federation
2. Provisioning
3. Identity as a service

My understanding for federation is that any access to cloud based services, can be intercepted and pointed to identity provider within the organization, which will then perform authentication and authorization, provide a token and the application can inspect token and allow/disallow access

For provisioning, instead of identity provider being located within organization, it can be located in cloud and it can refer to identity stores in cloud, which are provisioned in batch or real time by standards such as SPML or SCIM

Is the above understanding correct?

Comment: When you say "access to cloud-based services can be intercepted", what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

An app being deployed to the cloud has little to do with identity federation or identity as a service. You could very well use Forms authentication on a cloud service.

The question is whether you want to make your app responsible for authenticating users or not. If you choose not to (which is likely a good thing), then you need to rely on a mechanism to outsource identity. The techniques to do this are referred to as "claims based identity", "identity federation", among others, and involve a number of protocols (e.g. SAML, SAML-P, WS-Federation, OAuth). These depend on the systems you want to use for authenticating users:

1. SAML/WS-Fed are typically used for enterprises (using AD for example)
2. OAuth is mostly used by consumer oriented systems (e.g. Facebook, etc).

So, depending on where your users are you might need to implement one or the other (or both).

Identity As a Service, means you use an external service provider to handle authentication with these providers for you. It is not a requirement and you could build this capability on your own.

Without details of your infrastructure and your app it is difficult to provide any guidance: ASP.NET? Java? nodejs?Azure? AWS? Heroku? Where are your users?